# DB: "table" has no column named "name column"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've this problem when I was launching the app, it made me this error:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table geophysics_table has no column named municipality
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting id_grid=1 culture_type= resolution_survey= soil_type= coordinates= finish_date= start_date= municipality= site= software= range= ctr= assistans= frequency_feeler= igm= max_depth= instrument_type= area_investigated= description_site= n_tab= author= acquisition_method= survey_method= ref_geo_map=
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table geophysics_table has no column named municipality (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO geophysics_table(id_grid,culture_type,resolution_survey,soil_type,coordinates,finish_date,start_date,municipality,site,software,range,ctr,assistans,frequency_feeler,igm,max_depth,instrument_type,area_investigated,description_site,n_tab,author,acquisition_method,survey_method,ref_geo_map) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
                      at com.example.giuse.secondly.DBTools.insertGrid(DBTools.java:85)
                      at com.example.giuse.secondly.NewSheet.saveData(NewSheet.java:104)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fa4f2464180, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

But I think I've entered the "municipality" in every part. This is the code of the db:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    String query = "CREATE TABLE geophysics_table ( id_grid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, site TEXT, " +
            "n_tab TEXT, municipality TEXT, ctr TEXT, igm TEXT, coordinates TEXT, ref_geo_map TEXT, description_site TEXT, soil_type TEXT, culture_type TEXT, survey_method TEXT, instrument_type TEXT, resolution_survey TEXT, area_investigated TEXT, acquisition_method TEXT, frequency_feeler TEXT, range TEXT,  max_depth TEXT, software TEXT, author TEXT, assistants TEXT, start_date TEXT, finish_date TEXT)";
```

Comment: Try creating a new DB table.

Comment: Have you recently ran the app without that column in the database and failed to change the database version to tell the app to recreate the table?

Comment: That column has been surely added **after** a previous app run.

Comment: Just uninstall your app from device and re run will solve your issue

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall and install app again ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to increase your database version.

After increasing, `onUpgrade` method will called.

So, you can drop all your tables here and call `onCreate`.

Example

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS firstTable");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS secondTable");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS thirdTable");
    onCreate(db);
}
```